# Cleaning up sources.list and sources.list.d

Tags: debian, apt

For some reason, mostly due to my incompetence, there is some invalid address ( ie `404` ) pointed by my `sources.list`, and from some files contained under `sources.list.d` ( this is an way extending sources.list, without modifying it, isn't?). Is there some command to remove not responding addresses, or should I write some script?

Comment: You can use [Debian Sources List Generator website](https://debgen.simplylinux.ch/) to find actual repositories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just `hash` out the incorrect entries & `apt-get clean && apt-get update`

Comment: yep this is the manual approach, I'm asking if there is something to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

*Note: This is a paraphrase (read: copy) of [another answer from Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/762815), however it is applicable here too.*

#### Installation

1. Install the prerequisites:

   ```
   sudo apt install python3-apt
   ```
2. Download the ZIP bundle (`aptsources-cleanup.pyz`) from the [latest release.](https://github.com/davidfoerster/aptsources-cleanup/releases/latest)
3. Mark the PYZ bundle as executable:

   ```
   chmod a+x aptsources-cleanup.pyz
   ```

#### Usage:

1. From the download location of the PYZ bundle (see step 2 above) run:

   ```
   sudo ./aptsources-cleanup.pyz
   ```
2. Follow the instructions appearing on the screen.